# How do I send sequential text messages in web demo (dialogflow)?

Tags: dialogflow-es

According to this article https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages, we can add upto 10 responses in the UI which are then sent sequentially to the user.

However in my web demo case only one of the response is being picked randomly.

Link to web demo: https://bot.dialogflow.com/8195cb64-1104-46e5-8d43-b153828d7205

Just say hi to reproduce. Below is my intent setup

[image: My intent setup]

Update: When I'm testing the exact same on the test console on the right hand side it is working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have not read it properly.
It says "**Text responses are available in all platforms. Your agent can send up to 10 sequential text messages in response to a user input (assuming no other message types are defined in the intent).To add a new line in the UI, press Shift+Enter.**"

1)The response you are sending are picked randomly by Dialogflow.

2)To solve your query, Your sequential responses will be sent as line break , that means you have to Enter your Response variant 1 and Press Shift+Enter to do line break and write Variant 2 and so on. [Screenshot for messages with line break.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyZND.png)
**Note** : The message will be sent as a single message with line breaks between Text you call as variations.

If You want to send variations as different sequential messages you will have to use fulfillment responses (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview)

You can use 
agent.add(`Message 1`);
agent.add(`Message 2`);
agent.add(`Message 3`);  .... as many as you want.